# Getting number of records by date in LINQ to SQL query even if no results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have written the following LINQ-to-SQL to enable me to get a total number of records by day.

There are a few modifications I'd like to make to it in order to have it fit my needs. I have made various attempts but haven't been able to get it right.

I'd like to list the last 9 days, even if there were no 'opens' during this time.
I'd also like to group by Day/Month instead of just Day as I'm doing below.

An example of the output I'd love to get would be:

```
DateString   Opens
===================
 9/5         0
10/5         0
11/5         3
```

etc...

```
public List<OpensOverTimeViewModel> GetOpensOverTimeViewModel(int eId)
{

    DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day).AddDays(-9);
    DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day).AddDays(1);

    var summary = (from p in db.Opens
                    where (p.ElementId == eId) && (p.Timestamp >= lastDate) && (p.Timestamp <= currentDate)
                    let k = new
                    {
                        Day = p.Timestamp.Day
                    }
                    group p by k into t
                    select new OpensOverTimeViewModel
                    {
                        DateString = t.Key.Day,
                        TotalOpens = t.Count(),
                        ElementName = ""
                    }).ToList();

    return summary;
}
```

Any help on how best to tackle this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can replace `new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day)` with `DateTime.Today`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a left join in code after you got the result back from the database

Put the below lines just before your `return summary;` line.

```
var allDates = from idx in Enumerable.Range(0, (currentDate - lastDate).Days)
               select lastDate.AddDays(idx);

summary = (
          from allDate in allDates
          join su in summary on allDate.Day equals su.DateString into x
          from su in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new OpensOverTimeViewModel
          {
              DateString = allDate.Day,
              TotalOpens = su == null ? 0 : su.TotalOpens,
              ElementName = ""
          }).ToList();
```

To group by day/month I suggest using the whole date, replacing `t.Key.Day` with `t.Key.Date` and changing `DateString` into a `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. The only question I have now would be how to list dd/MM as the DateString. When I concatenate the strings, LINQ-to-SQL compliains.

Comment: "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: Hi Albin - This doesn't work and gives the same error as above.

Comment: If you your database dates have empty time-parts you can use `t.Key` instead of `t.Key.Date`, if not you need to group on `new{t.Key.Day, t.Key.Month, t.Key.Year}`.

Comment: Hi Albin. Appreicate you've gone above and beyond with this answer, but would you be able to provide me an example to provide some context. I can't seem to get this to play nicely! Thanks, Nick.